# loading other css from child theme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just made my first child theme and it is working fine. But there are other css that needs to be changed which is loading from the parent and its dir structure is themes/css/layout.css
So I need to make that css load through child

I tired to do like this:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Artificer
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-thirteen-child/
 Description:  artificer Child Theme
 Author:       Rabin Shrestha
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     artificer
 Version:      1.0.0
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  twenty-fourteen-child
*/


/*
@import url("../artificer/css/layout.css");
*/

/* =Theme customization starts here
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

and put the other css below and also put that css directory and layout.css inside the child theme but nothing happned. please help me

Comment: Why is everything commented out?

Comment: @AndreYonadam coz that is the way we should initialize the header as said here -> http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/wordpress-child-theme-tutorial with title getting started

Comment: Yeah but your commenting out your import css and maybe the theme customization which I don't know because you don't have any css below.

Comment: I do have it is more than 3000 lines... Should I post it???

Comment: remove the comment from the import

Answer (score 1):

I realize your attempt to comment out the parent theme's css is intentional (unlike commenters)...and you have also tried to implement your own css.

Your issue is that most likely artificer (i'm not entirely familiar with that theme) most likely enqueues (or references) their other CSS files directly...and not via css imports.  This is why your attempts at preventing that theme from loading their css files (and not your own) are not working.

Two possible solutions.

1. If the artificier author created conditional checks (is function defined) around the methods that enqueue their css files...you can use define your own function with same name to enqueue your own css files. Not too many theme authors do this though.
2. The not so elegant way...is to just include a CSS override file that gets called after artificier css files that applies the tweaks you want done.